# Telegram bot авторизация через чат

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста, пишу телеграм бота (на питоне) и хочу реализовать авторизацию через собственное API для получения данных из БД.
Возможно такое? Если да, направьте, где копать инфу. Спасибо.

Пример общения с ботом: 
Человек: Зайди в личный кабинет. 
Бот: Назови логин и пароль (через пробел). 
Ч: login pass 
Бот: Отлично. Вы авторизированы. 
Ч: Выведи количество записей в таблице А. 
Б: Сделано. 150.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю возможно, сделать таблицу юзеров в БД для хранения паролей напр. поля `[user_id, password]`, пароль хранить в виде хеша, юзер вводит `/login <password>`, бот распарсивает строку и проверяет хеш введённого пароля и хеш в бд соответствующий этому юзеру (при этом нужно ввести регистрацию при подключении бота для занесения в БД пароля), только надо придумать как хранить сессию (например можно добавить в таблицу юзеров поле с датой (тогда поля таблица будут выглядеть так: `[user_id, password, session_date]`), до которой работает сессия, если текущая дата меньше даты в поле `session_date`, то юзер авторизован, если больше - то нет и необходима авторизация, после которой поле `session_date` обновляется (например время сессии - час, тогда записываем в поле `текущее время текущей даты + час`), если юзер разлогинился сам `/logout`, то в поле `session_date` пишем, например, `0` (если дату и время храним в Unix Timestamp), тогда юзер будет "неавторизован").
Уверен что боты могут юзать БД, т.к. другие боты "запоминали" некоторые введённые мною данные.

Если что, не писал ботов для телеги (но планирую как только руки дойдут, и даже заинтересовался этой идеей и попробую её воплотить, уверен что это возможно), и лишь предполагаю, как можно реализовать, так что не кидайтесь палками сразу, если я в чём то не прав.
Если ставите минусы за мои какие-либо ошибки, то, будьте добры, пишите в комментариях причину и в чём не прав, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В ближайшее время попробую реализовать. Отпишусь, что получилось.